# Run command after hostile mob is killed

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Monster;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        
    }
    public class MobListener implements Listener {
         
        @EventHandler
        public void onEntityDeath(EntityDeathEvent event) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int randomInt = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
            int[] myNum = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
            int[] uncommon = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
            int[] rare = {1,2,3,4,5};
            int[] epic = {1,2};
            int[] legendary = {1};
            int[] a = IntStream.range(1, 100).toArray();
            if(event.getEntity() instanceof Monster)
            {
                Monster monsterEnt = (Monster) event.getEntity();
                if(monsterEnt.getKiller() instanceof Player)
                {
                    Player mcPlayer = (Player)monsterEnt.getKiller();
                    if(mcPlayer == null)
                        return;
                    if(mcPlayer.hasPermission("customdrops.use"))
                        for(int i : myNum)
                            if(randomInt == i)
                                Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "crate give to" + mcPlayer + "CommonChest");
                        for(int i : uncommon)
                            if(randomInt == i)
                                Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "crate give to" + mcPlayer + "UncommonChest");
                        for(int i : rare)
                            if(randomInt == i)
                                Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "crate give to" + mcPlayer + "RareChest");
                        for(int i : epic)
                            if(randomInt == i)
                                Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "crate give to" + mcPlayer + "EpicChest");
                        for(int i : legendary)
                            if(randomInt == i)
                                Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "crate give to" + mcPlayer + "LegendaryChest");
                        for(int i : a)
                            if(randomInt == i)
                                Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "give" + mcPlayer + "dirt 64");
                }
            }
        } 
    } 

}
```

I added in the dirt thing just to test and so far no crates or dirt has been dropped. No errors in console, plugin shows up green in /pl. Using 1.16.2. I want it to run commands when hostile mobs are killed. The commands will give them crates or dirt (for now, this will be removed).

Comment: don't you need a space before and after mcPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a valid command.

This is your command `"crate give to" + mcPlayer + "CommonChest"`, lets break it down.

First, I am pretty sure that you cannot reference a Player object directly in a command.

```
//In-Correct
mcPlayer 

//Correct
mcPlayer.getDisplayName()
```

Secondly, you need to add spaces either side of the player name

```
//In-Correct
`"abc" + mcPlayer + "def"`

//Correct
`"abc " + mcPlayer + " def"`
```

Now all together:

```
Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "crate give to " + mcPlayer.getDisplayName() + " CommonChest");
```

Note: Are you sure that this is a valid command registered by a plugin: `crate give to Toasterr1066 CommonChest`?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the code yet it still does not run. Secondly, that command is from a crates plugin and is a valid plugin. The command does run, however I am not receiving the dirt. Earlier, it would say unknown command because I did not have the spaces so I know it is running, however I am just no receiving the items. Here is the updated code: https://pastebin.com/YV515CBs

Comment: Update: Everything is working now expect it gives 100 crates. Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/33GQJ6t7

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see, you are not registering your listener class.

You can do it with this following line inside your `onEnable()` method.

```java
Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MobListener());
```